# rails / passenger: using environment variable for memcache server address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, passenger

I am trying to set up our Rails app to pull the address of the memcache server from an environment variable (we have 2 'production' environments, one for testing and one for live, and hence can't have different environments files).

This is a Rails 2.3.11 app, not rails 3.

I have this in my environments/production.rb file:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, ENV['MEMCACHE_SERVERS'] || 'localhost:11211'
```

If I fire up a Rails console and do:

```
Rails.cache.stats
```

I see that it is using the right one out of the environment variable (set in /etc/environments on our ubuntu servers).

But, if our actual running rails app fired up via passenger it is using localhost!

Does Passenger not use the environment or am I doing something else wrong?

If there is a better way of doing this of course I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Apache directive `SetEnv` or the equivalent for your server? The environment is heavily modified for Apache sub-processes, of which Passenger is one.

Comment: Thanks - we are using Nginx. Seems silly that we would have to set environment variables in the webserver, not the environment... but I'll give it a shot!

Comment: It's not too silly when you think about it. As your web server is initialized by `init` it doesn't have the same environment as a full user shell. Most servers also completely re-define the environment so it is consistent for sub-processes regardless of how the server was started.

Comment: I actually couldn't find a way to pass it from nginx either.

Comment: Maybe it's not supported? See: [How do I pass environment variables to nginx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492718/how-do-i-pass-imagemagick-environment-variables-to-nginx-mongrels)

Comment: Is there anything that would preclude using a configuration file instead of an environment variable? I thought `config/memcache.yml` was pretty standard.