# nginx home environment variable?

Tags: bash, nginx, environment-variables

I have some nginx config in a repo, and the application root is sometimes different on different machines and setups:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.triface.local;

    root /Users/xxxxxx/Sites/triface-admin/public;
    index triface.html;
}
```

I want to set a variable somewhere (like an bash environment variable or equivalent) that lets me avoid hardcoding the server root.  It seems like this should be straightforward, but I can't find anything on it.  Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is, there isn't any!  Intentionally!  And once I read the reasoning, it actually made sense.  Though it is a bummer I can't do local nginx installs to people's $HOME dir, but I can live with that.

See this stackoverflow answer:

[How do I pass ImageMagick environment variables to nginx mongrels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492718/how-do-i-pass-imagemagick-environment-variables-to-nginx-mongrels)

Answer (score -2):

Sure:

```
set $homedir /Users/xxxxxx/Sites/triface-admin/public;
```

Then just call $homedir

Comment: This is for the nginx config file. To set an environment variable e.g. in your .bashrc, the syntax is simply `NGINX=/Users/xxxxxx/Sites/triface-admin/public`

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I thought that he wanted to set it in Nginx.

Comment: Yeah, looking for a way to set a bash environment variable and read it from nginx (like $HOME), but apparently there isn't any!